# How to config an instance (folder) inside redis database

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using c# with StackExchange.Redis.
I used something like this to connect :

```
    var client = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_appSettings["Cache:Redis:Configuration"]);
    _database = client.GetDatabase(int.Parse(_appSettings["Cache:Redis:LockProcessDB"]));
```

and then I access the set / get commands via :

```
_database.StringSet(data.Key, data.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_ttl), When.NotExists, CommandFlags.None);
...
```

I now need to divide different "sections" in my data into different "folders" in the redis database.
So instead of just setting values under DB 7, I want DB 7 to have a sub folder called : Documents and the values I am setting should be inserted under that folder.

In the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed` for .net core solution they support in registering it like this :

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
                {
                    options.Configuration = ConfigUtils.Instance.Get("Redis_Config", "");
                    options.InstanceName = "Documents:";
                });
```

which then directs my set commands into the "Documents" sub folder. 
How do I achieve that with StackExchange.Redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I didnt understand an important part about separation in a Redis DB.
The option for a prefix and the way to use it.

When trying to set a value I can actually add a prefix like -

```
string _prefix = "documents:";

_database.StringSet(_prefix + data.Key, data.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_ttl), When.NotExists, CommandFlags.None);
```

Which achieves the desired result.

The data saves in my redis DB as `documents:myKey` under a folder named "documents"